# Code shows on Android Studio Preview but not on Smartphone

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I wrote some very simple code with one image and two text views in a Relative Layout.

It all seems fine in the preview but as soon as I try to run the code on my phone, one text view disappears.

I have tried everything, but can't fix the problem (check out the screenshots).

Code in Android Studio Preview

[image: img]

Code on my smartphone

[image: img]

This is my code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hb_isabel"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hb_isabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Happy Birthday,Isabel!"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="From, Nathalie"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` with Vertical orientation rather than `RelativeLayout`, things will be a lot easier.

Comment: don't know whether it solves your issue but here are three thoughts related to your layout xml:
1) make the height of the relative layout also match parent
2) define the textview first with android:id="@+id/hb_isabel" and reference it in your imageview with android:layout_below="@id/hb_isabel"
3) should be the height of the imageview really be match parent ?

Comment: Is that your entire layout? Is some other layout covering the text view?